# how can i change some days background color in Applandeo calendarview

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar

i want to change some days background color to other color but it doesnt work that i expect

```
        val calendarView: CalendarView = attendanceInquiryBinding.attendanceCalendarView

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2024)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15)

        val greenBackgroundDrawable = ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.greencal))

        val eventDay = EventDay(calendar, greenBackgroundDrawable)

        val eventDaysList = mutableListOf<EventDay>()
        eventDaysList.add(eventDay)

        calendarView.setEvents(eventDaysList)

        val list = listOf(
            CalendarDay(calendar).apply {
               // labelColor = [color resource]
                backgroundResource = R.drawable.calendar_selected

            }
        )

        calendarView.setCalendarDays(list)
```

thats my code but it has empty space like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwV3D.png)
what can i do to fill up the color of the background

Answer (score 1):

Please check sample module in [Material-Calendar-View](https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View/tree/develop/sample) library. There are an examples where calendar background is same as day background and selected is marked with an image not the background.

If howeather you need remove margins between week rows when days are selected please modify `calendar_view_picker_day.xml` in such way:

Set `<LinearLayout` height same as child textView so `android:layout_height="@dimen/day_label_size_events_disabled"`.
Set `<LinearLayout android:padding="0dp"`

All modifications:

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="@dimen/day_label_size_events_disabled"
>     android:background="@drawable/day_picker_item_background"
>     android:padding="0dp"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>     <TextView ....
> ```